# Web scraping. First page data duplicated

Tags: python, dataframe, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Here is code using Bs4 and pandas dataframe to scrape two websites' data . second page successfully scraped but instead of showing second page data first page's data duplicated .

---

```py
@app.route('/')
def index():
    try:
        webpage1 = requests.get('https://bekorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts')
        sp1 = BeautifulSoup(webpage1.content, 'html.parser')
        webpage2 = requests.get('https://perfectorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts-1')
        sp2 = BeautifulSoup(webpage2.content, 'html.parser')
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle the exception here, e.g. log the error, display an error message to the user, etc.
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            return "Sorry, we could not process your request at this time. Please try again later."    


    data1 = []
    for i in range(1, 3):
        #Extracting data from first website
    
        url = f'https://bekorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts?page={i}'
        webpage = requests.get(url)
        sp = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, 'html.parser')
        title1 = sp.find_all('div', 'card__information')
        sellprice1 = sp.find_all('span', 'price-item price-item--regular')
        for title0, sellprice0 in zip(title1, sellprice1):
            title_text = title0.find('a').text
            price_text= sellprice0.text
            if title_text and price_text:
                product = {'Name of Product': title_text.strip(), 'Selling Price': re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', price_text.strip())}
                data1.append(product)
        next_page = sp.find('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
```

[two websites scraped data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5A3P.png) 
First page data keep repeating and i am trying to avoid data repeating and trying to scrape next page data

Comment: I haven't solved your problem but just an FYI you can add "/products.json" to the end of the url to get pretty json back instead of having to parse html   https://perfectorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts-1/products.json & https://bekorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts/products.json

Answer (score 0):

**Mis-aligned data is a common issue that crops up when you `zip` lists together** without checking whether they are actually aligned with each other.

> *but instead of showing second page data first page's data duplicated*

It's not just the first page data - **names** from *all* pages are duplicate (not the prices though). Add `print(len(title1), 'titles and', len(sellprice1), 'prices from', url)` just before the ***`for title0, sellprice0 ...`*** loop and you'll see that there are always twice as many items in `title1` as there are in `sellprice1` ([**view screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMBke.png)).

---

Rather than zipping different ResultSets together, it would be better to loop through a single ResultSet of elements that [contain all the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlYkq.png) you might want in a row. Something like

```py
        for product in sp.find_all('li', class_='grid__item'):
            title = product.find('div', class_='card__information')
            if title: title = title.find('a')
            price = product.find('span', class_='price-item price-item--regular')
            if title and title:
                data1.append({
                    'Name of Product': title.text.strip(), 
                    'Selling Price': re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', price.text.strip())
                })
```

or with [`.select`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) and [list comprehension](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/list-comprehension):

```py
        title_sel,price_sel = 'div.card__information a','span.price-item.price-item--regular'
        product_sel = f'li.grid__item:has({title_sel}):has({price_sel})'

        data1 += [{
            'Name of Product': product.select_one(title_sel).text.strip(),
            'Selling Price': re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', product.select_one(price_sel).text.strip())
        } for product in sp.select(product_sel)]
```

---

> ```py
>         next_page = sp.find('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
> ```

If you fix this (`.find('a', {'href':True, 'aria-label':"Next page"})`), you can change to a while loop:

```py
    max_pg = None # 2 # 10 # set any limit
    url = f'https://bekorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts'

    data1, cur_pg = [], 0
    title_sel,price_sel = 'div.card__information a','span.price-item.price-item--regular'
    product_sel = f'li.grid__item:has({title_sel}):has({price_sel})'
    while url and (cur_pg:=cur_pg+1)<=(max_pg if max_pg is not None else cur_pg): 
        sp = BeautifulSoup((webpage:=requests.get(url)).content, 'html.parser')
        
        data1 += [{
          'Name of Product': product.select_one(title_sel).text.strip(),
          'Selling Price': re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', product.select_one(price_sel).text.strip())
        } for product in sp.select(product_sel)]

        nextPg = sp.find('a', {'href':True, 'aria-label':"Next page"})
        url = 'https://bekorganics.myshopify.com'+nextPg['href'] if nextPg else None
```

---

> *"...FYI you can add "/products.json" to the end of the url to get pretty json back instead of having to parse html..."* - [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75822874/web-scraping-first-page-data-duplicated#comment133747921_75822874) by [childnick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11338900/childnick)

Then you don't have to bother with looping through pagination at all.

```py
json_url = 'https://bekorganics.myshopify.com/collections/nuts/products.json'
json_data = requests.get(json_url).json()
data1 = [{
    'Name of Product': p['title'], 'Selling Price': f"£{p['variants'][0]['price']}"
} for p in json_data['products']]
```

---

With any of the above suggestions, the output should look like:

[image: opdf1]